# WPBakery Single Image element - load dynamically

Tags: wordpress, shortcode, wpbakery

I have a WPBakery custom block with shortcode `[porto_block id="47722"]` that uses a *Single Image* element.

This element's source code typically looks like this:

```
[vc_single_image image="9999" img_size="large" alignment="center"]
```

In my case, I wanted to be able to alter the image at will, so I defined it like this:

```
[vc_single_image image="##IMAGE##" img_size="large" alignment="center"]
```

My plan was to replace the placeholder text `##IMAGE##` while calling the block.

So in my functions.php the code that would call the block looked like this:

```
echo str_replace('##IMAGE##', $image, do_shortcode('[porto_block id="47722"]')); // $image is calculated earlier in my code
```

However, I realized that `do_shortcode()`, when called, has already rendered the WPBakery's *Single Image* element, so I'm not given the chance to replace my placeholder text with an actual image ID. Thus, the final page looks like this:

[image]

How can I call a shortcode at an earlier than the rendering stage?

Comment: You would essentially need to create your own shortcode that wraps the `vc_single_image` shortcode, so you can alter the output. Or if `vc_single_image` has some sort of `apply_filters` for the image id - those are your options.

Comment: @disinfor so there is no way to intercept the do_shortcode() before it actually renders the content of the shortcode? There are other problems that arouse from the first approach you mentioned. For example, there is a table that appears in place of another placeholder text. So, normally, the table would simply be inside the `<div class="wpb_wrapper"></div>`, but the way I do it, replacing a ##CHART## placeholder with the table, the markup of the table gets wrapped up by a <p></p>, as before replacement it was rendered like `<p>##CHART##</p>`...